# SonarLint intent clarification

Tags: c#, sonarlint

I was searching for an extension to integrate VS with Sonar, in order to avoid waiting for Sonar to run to have a feedback on my code. Live feedback is really valuable in addition to shared feedback through Sonar UI (providing shared ruleset, history, tendance, analysis...).

I had seen plugins for Eclipse & IntelliJ in last years, which were running Sonar analysis (based on shared ruleset), leveraging incremental analysis also...

Lately, I found [vssonarextension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7fc312c3-f1ab-49f8-b286-dbf7fff37305) that seems to do pretty much the same thing (incremental & preview analysis) for C# projects in Visual Studio.
But I also found the official SonarLint (recently renamed from SonarQube for C#), and I can't catch how it works. It seems to be disconnected from SonarQube server and to reimplement rules already implemented on server (through C# plugin), am I wrong ? Can you clarify ?

Answer (score 5):

[SonarLint for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47d1049d-bb27-454e-aab8-24566c85e548) is based on the new .NET compiler framework (Roslyn), which is shipped within Visual Studio 2015. This extension is working on individual developer machines, and (at the moment) is not connected to the SonarQube server.

To share a set of common rules between developer machines, you can save and commit a ruleset file along with your solution. On each developers machine this ruleset file will be picked up by the .NET compiler framework, and therefore by SonarLint too. (If you don't want to install the SonarLint VS extension, you have the option to ship this functionality along the solution in the form of a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarLint))

To see the analysis result on a SonarQube server, you would need to use the MsBuild SonarQube Runner ([more info](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin)). This internally uses the SonarLint assemblies, and adds a few more rules that need parameters that are specified on the server.

Comment: My question seems wider in fact...:)

I understood that MSBuild SonarQube Runner was just a wrapper around the (old) SonarQube Runner, that runs analysis using the C# plugin. This plugin had the rules (sonar-cssquid). If I well understand, rules have been moved from plugin to SonarLint for VS ?

Answer (score 2):

1. SonarLint for Visual Studio integrates with Visual Studio 2015 and provides live feedback, as you code, on quality flaws. It also automatically suggests code fixes. It has no connection with the SonarQube server: you won't be able to see for example all new issues introduced since the last SonarQube analysis, comment on issues, and so on. We're working with Microsoft to improve that overtime.
2. vssonarextension is an unofficial Visual Studio extension (also ) for SonarQube. It is not developed and not supported by SonarSource. My understanding is that this extension is an attempt to replicate the Eclipse / IntelliJ SonarQube plugins
3. Speaking about the Eclipse / IntelliJ SonarQube plugins (soon to be rebranded into SonarLint for Eclipse / IntelliJ) - these are both in advance of SonarLint for Visual Studio, because they have this connection to the SonarQube server, but also lag behind because of the lack of real-time (or close to real-time) feedback. The Eclipse SonarQube plugin has a new feature to analyze files each time they are saved, improving the experience. Moreover, none of two is able to suggest code fixes for now.
4. The MSBuild SonarQube Runner is not simply a "wrapper" around the sonar-runner: It captures information about your project during the actual `msbuild` build, forces the FxCop execution, and so on. Yes, in version 1.0, the `end` phase will invoke the sonar-runner, but this really is just an implementation detail. Newer versions of the SonarQube server will allow analysis reports to be uploaded through a web service, instead of relying on direct accesses from the sonar-runner to the database. So in the future, we can imagine a pure C# implementation of the MSBuild SonarQube Runner, which could work without having to install Java.
5. The SonarQube C# Plugin is providing C# support in SonarQube. You obviously cannot install SonarLint for Visual Studio in SonarQube, as it is an extension for Visual Studio 2015... Now, the SonarQube C# Plugin internally embeds some version of SonarLint VS: It launches a Windows executable that will re-use the same .dll files that the Visual Studio extension uses. This way, there is not need to duplicate the rule implementations.

Feel free to have a look at the sources if you want more details on how this works exactly:

- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vs
- https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-csharp